# How to Grant access to specific LDAP user in Gitlab

Tags: git, ldap, gitlab

LDAP user login is working seamlessly with Gitlab. But the problem is, currently everyone in LDAP is able to login to Gitlab and view the workspace. I want to restrict the view and access to very few within the LDAP group. I tried adding new user, but it is not allowing me to specify whether this is a local user (like root) or LDAP user and suppose if the user exists in LDAP, I am getting the error "Email/username has already been taken".

Is there a way to restrict the access only to specific LDAP user within Gitlab.

Comment: GItlab ce or ee?

Comment: I am using GITLAB CE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restricting LDAP cannot be done through Sign in or Sign up but only through LDAP settings in gitlab.rb file.

The syntax to allow a specific user is user_filter: `user_filter: (&(objectClass=user)(memberOf=CN=gitlabaccess,OU=mail-distribution-groups,OU=staff,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com))`. Specify your CN, OU and DC attributes.

The syntax to deny or not to include specific user is `(!(cn=username))`.

GitLab gave a [document](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/ldap.html#using-an-ldap-filter-to-limit-access-to-your-gitlab-server) on LDAP user filter option.

Also go through LDAP RFC 4145 [document](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4515)

Comment: I am now restricting the access within the group with user_filter. In the user_filter, i am adding a single group where all my necessary users are available and thereby granting automatic access to the restricted user base.

Answer (score 0):

To restrict access to ldap users follow next instructions.

If you want to make your project privete or to hide it from some Ldap/non-Ldap users  you will need to go to:

*Your_Project/settings/General_Project_Settings/permissions*

Then set option "Project visibility" on "private".

When project visibility is set on private no one can see the project workspace if it is not manualy added as a project user ( or master, develepor...).

In This case project will be hiden from all users and it will be restriceted to users who are not enroled on the project.

Or in your case you can set the already created project as a private and unenroll wanted users, the users that are unenroled from a private project will be restriced to access/view project workspace.

Users can be unenroled from project following this steps:

Your_Project/settings/members

Then click on a sign from [This Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlaJv.png) to unenrol user from project.

**Note:** You can make changes on Git project configuration only if you are project owner.

Answer (score 0):

Any way to restrict LDAP access to existing users only?

That is stop LDAP login from creating user profiles!